# RavenDB - migrate multiple databases from 3.5 to 4.2

Tags: migration, ravendb

We have an appllication that uses more than 300 databases in one ravenDB instance. (One for every customer.)

Now we want to migrate to RavenDB 4.2 (from 3.5) and need to migrate all the data too.
And we not want to migrate every database for its own.
I was searching and I found a lot of descriptions to migrate one DB (and that's working fine) but not for more than one.

I don't care if it is done by code or any tool.

Any good ideas out there?

Answer (score 3):

Easiest would be to set up one-way replication from 3.5 to 4.2 (you can do this by code for each database by modifying the replication destinations for each database)